# Battery drain with repeated logs of ‘bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port’

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, sleep-wake, catalina

I’ve noticed battery drain on my MacBook Pro 2018 when sleeping from 100 to 1 overnight since I've updated to Catalina. This log is showing every couple of seconds when sleeping:

```
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip syslogd[944]: ASL Sender Statistics
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19482]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19485]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19483]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19484]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19486]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:05 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19481]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:06 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19487]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 21 09:45:06 MacBook-Pro-Filip xpcproxy[19488]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up
```

Comment: Not sure about the logs, but try turning off wifi overnight. I have bad drain on my 2019 MBP, turning off wifi has lessened the drain.

Comment: This is a common message on the log, there is nothing to worry about it. It is informative, telling that the Inter Process Communication Port of those process [used by the BSD subsystem of MacOS] are closed. This is normal, informative.